# Test Coverage Colour - Backend of React Native App

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, jestjs, nestjs

**npm run test:cov**

Very new to server side programming need some guidance.
In my Test report below, it says the "if" is not covered.

[image]

No matter how I write the if logic it throws this error.
How do I fix this?? 
Where and what should I look for??

**Update:**

Below is my test data:

```
const input = {
      applicationId,
      subApplicationId: 'test',
      alert: '0 General',
      badge: 1,
      sound: 'default',
      createDate: '2020-03-30T03:43:45.773Z',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
      }),
    };
    await notificationService.create(input);

  });

  

  it('General', async () => {
    expect(
      await notificationController.retrieve(
        {
          applicationId,
          targetId: 'B9EF21EE-EA9B-4C9E-9D77-949A7A944AF9',
          requestDate: '2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z',
        },
        buildRequest({ isAuthorized: false }),
      ),
    ).toHaveLength(3);
  });

  it('General + Personal', async () => {
    expect(
      await notificationController.retrieve(
        {
          applicationId,
          userId: '2019040913083656642537',
          targetId: 'B9EF21EE-EA9B-4C9E-9D77-949A7A944AF9',
          requestDate: '2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z',
        },
        buildRequest({ isAuthorized: true }),
      ),
    ).toHaveLength(7);
  });

  it('General + Personal (with userId)', async () => {
    expect(
      await notificationController.retrieve(
        {
          applicationId,
          userId: '2019040913083656642537',
          requestDate: '2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z',
        },
        buildRequest({ isAuthorized: true }),
      ),
    ).toHaveLength(2);
  });
```

Comment: I'd be looking for a test where `input.userId` is set but `input.targetId` isn't, that's what would cause the program flow to enter that block.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes you are right. Please see my updated question I have added the test cases. The 3rd test case is the issue. I want to be able to retrieve my notifications using just "userId". Hence I created the index "appuserId" and I wrote my query logic accordingly. But when I run my test cases it does not seem to enter that block. What else can I do??

Comment: As I mentioned in previous questions dedicated to this problem, you need to provide stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that allows to fully understand what's going on on your side. Separate snippets are not enough. If args from `retrieve` call in `(with userId)` were directly translated to input, you would have `input.userId` truthy and `input.targetId === undefined` and this would cover the 2nd condition. The logic behind this is very straightforward and that this doesn't happen means that retrieve doesn't work like you expect. Only you can debug it for now.

Comment: And another possibility is that the coverage is misconfigured and refers to another line, this may happen if sourcemaps went wrong. This seemed to be the case for a snippet from one of your questions. This requires to examine your case in detail, too. It's impossible to give a qualified answer to your question at this point, even if it's asked in different ways.

Comment: This happens because you aren't writing a test case without passing the `input.userId` and `input.targetId` so the _if_ statement is not covered by any test.